# How do I create groups of data with different details?

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a detail report for contracts related to a project. I want the report to include all contracts associated with the project, contract items and then the invoice and change order details for each contract item. I know I can use groups to create the contract and contract items sections of this report, but I don't know how (or even if it's possible) to associate the invoice and change order details to the contract item. The attached image is a mock-up of what I would like this report to look like. Can someone please advise if this is possible, and if so, how I would implement it with SSRS?

[Contract Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxdUv.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could approach this but my instinct would be to use a combination of sub reports and groups. It really depends on what your data looks like.

Just going on the sample you posted....

I would create a sub-report that takes a single contract item as a parameter or parameters. For example, if each contract item has a unique ID you could pass that to the sub-report, if the contract item is unique with in contract then you would pass in both a contract number and contract item number. I would then create a master report to call the subreport for each item.

So,

**Creating the sub-report**

1. Create a report (let's call it 'contractItem`) that displays the data for a single contract item only.
2. Add parameter(s) as required, just enough to make the report unique - see previous comments about this.
3. Add datasets to get the data for each part of the report (item details, invoice details, change order details). Make sure the dataset queries filter the data to the specific contract item e.g. `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ContractItemID = @pContractItemID` . Where `pContractItemID` is the name of your report's parameter.
4. Add tables to display the contents of your dataset(s)
5. Test the report and make sure it does what you expect
6. Don't put any page headers/footers in and get rid of any unnecessary white space around the report content.
7. Save the report

**Next create the main report**

8. Create a new report.
9. Add a dataset (e.g. `dsLoop`) that contains all the contract numbers and contract item numbers. e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ContractNumber, ContractItemID FROM myTable ORDER BY ContractNumber, ContractItemID`
   This will give us something like

| ContractNumber | ContractPartID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |
| 456 | 1 |

10. Now Add a table and bind it to the dataset (set the tablix's dataset
    property)
11. Remove all but a single row and make the remaining cell wider just so it's easier to work with.
12. Right click the cell and insert -> subreport
13. Set the subreport to be the report we created earlier (`contractItem`)
14. In the properties tab, set the properties of the subreport to be the value of the field(s) from your `dsLoop` dataset created earlier.
15. Add a parent row group (include a header when prompted) that groups on ContractNumber. You can add the contract number etc to this row group, merge the cells if required.

When you run the report, it will produce a single row for each entry in you `dsLoop` dataset. Each row will contain a sub-report and each of those sub-report will have the parameters passed from the corresponding record in `dsLoop`

Hopefully some of that made sense...
If not, look at some of my other answers over the years, there might be a couple that have some similar solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will give this a try!